# префиксный и постфиксный инкремент

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a =1,b;
    b = ++a*a++; 
    std :: cout<< b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Объясните почему тут 6, а не 4?

Comment: Включаем варнинги и видим что-то типа `warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'a'`. Это неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно это выполнилось следующим образом (по шагам):

1. `++a * a++` //Значение a = 1;
2. `&a * a++` Префиксный инкремент увеличил значение "a" и вернул на нее ссылку (Обозначим, как &а). //Значение a = 2;
3. `&a * 2` Постфиксный инкремент вернул текущее значение переменной (т.е. 2) и увеличил значение "a". //Значение a = 3;
4. `3 * 2 = 6;`

Comment: Сюда нужна жирная приписка про UB.